# Expired permesso di soggiorno. I don't have a ricevuta

Tags: italy

Because of a serious emergency I had to go back to my home country. I was given an appointment for ricevuta in 5 months. So I had no choice. I went to my home country with an exired permesso di soggiorn. Now I only have an old permesso di soggiorno expired for almost a year, which is definitely older than the 60 days to apply for a re-entry visa.

Does anyone have an idea what I should do? Should I apply for a re-entry visa even if the soggiorno is expired for more than a year?

Comment: Contact the Italian embassy and explain the situation, and provide all documentation you can proving the emergency and that you could not get an ppointment for the ricevuta any earlier. My guess is you're not getting back in without repeating the process all over again, but again ask them

Comment: VTC: this is a [duplicate of what OP asked earlier](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/120607/permesso-di-soggiorno-expired-for-more-than-a-year-i-dont-have-ricevuta-how-t)